# Objective-C NSInteger formatting confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know I'm missing something obvious here but I can't seem to get my nsinteger stuff write for passing variables and putting them into strings.  Here is the part of code that is jacked up.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *chosenCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //need to get the ID number for this guy
    NSInteger id_number = chosenCell.tag;
    NSLog(@"This is the id number I'm sending to the item list %@", id_number);
    NSLog(@"This is the id number I'm sending to the item list %i", id_number);
    ItemViewController *vc = [[ItemViewController alloc] initWithPlayer:id_number andGame:gameId];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

The problem is that if I print using the %@ it works properly, however it really shouldn't as this is not an object that is being printed but an integer.   If I use the integer call, it functions wrong, giving me a really off the wall integer.  This sounds like the answer is just "use %@" but the problem is that in other cases when I tried to use that as the solution(such as on the next controller), I get an exc_bad_access.  Please tell me I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%i` will work, according to [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

[A `UIView`'s tag is an NSInteger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag), which is what `%i` specifies.

Comment: However your comment just made me realize what I was doing.  The problem was not with printing it, it was where the tag was being set.   I had simply tried to "cast" a string into an NSInteger rather than using the integerValue method.  THis fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To work on both 32 bit and 64 bit systems you should correctly use `%ld` or `%lx` as specified in the apple documentation here (under the heading Platform Dependencies):
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Edit: Ah.  Sorry.  This is iOS not Mac OS.